# When is this effect size for chi-squared appropriate?

Tags: correlation, chi-squared-test, meta-analysis, effect-size

A paper I am reviewing contains the following measure of effect size for chi-squared

$r = \sqrt{\frac{\chi^2_{obs}}{df+2}}$

where $\chi^2_{obs}$ is observed chi-squared and $df$ is its associated degrees of freedom.

This seems kinda like the Phi coefficient except it's dividing by $df+2$ instead of $N$. It's also somewhat similar to Cramer's $V$. The paper in question doesn't name the measure of effect size, and my searching hasn't revealed anything.

The paper seeks to aggregate effect sizes across chi-squared statistics reported in thousands of psychology papers, with the ultimate goal being to track changes in reported effect sizes over time. A bot scraped the papers for any chi-squared statistic reported in APA style, and collected the reported test statistic value and the associated degrees of freedom and $p$-value. The chi-squared statistics collected are highly diverse in terms of their degrees of freedom and also the contexts in which they were used.

Although I am interested in whether this measure of effect size was an appropriate selection for that particular paper, I am mainly wondering under what general circumstances this measure of effect size would be appropriate? In particular, would it be appropriate irrespective of what kind of chi-squared test is being done (goodness of fit, independence, etc), irrespective of the context in which the chi-squared statistic arose (analyses of contingency tables, simple regression, etc), and irrespective of how many degrees of freedom there are? Also, does it have a name?

Comment: Could you share information about the context and how this statistic is computed?  After all, chi-squared statistics crop up in myriad unrelated situations and are computed in a wide variety of ways, so perhaps that detail will suggest the motivation for the $df+2$ factor.

Comment: The context for the paper is that it seeks to aggregate effect sizes across thousands of papers, with the ultimate goal being to track changes in reported effect sizes over time. A bot scrapes $\chi^2$, $F$, $r$, and $t$ statistics from papers that are required to use APA style. It doesn't scrape the $N$ but it does scrape the $df$ and other features (test statistic value, $p$-value, etc). So in terms of motivation the author would be hoping that the effect size would be valid across all those myriad situations and computations, or at least among a clear majority of them.

Comment: Let me clarify, then: one possibility is that all these $\chi^2$ values arise in simple regression settings where $df+2$ is the number of observations, which would make this effect size a root mean square residual.  But if these $\chi^2$ values arise, say, in analyses of contingency tables, that interpretation is impossible.  What, then, is the form of the $\chi^2$ statistics that are being aggregated and what kind of analysis is producing them?

Comment: The bot scrapes all $\chi^2$ statistics reported in APA style, and then the author seeks to aggregate the effect sizes $r = \sqrt{\frac{\chi^2_{obs}}{df+2}}$ irrespective of what kind of $\chi^2$ analysis produced them. Some of the $\chi^2$ statistics would arise in simple regression settings, others from analyses of contingency tables, and others from different settings. The author lacks a way to determine which scraped $\chi^2$ results come from which settings: all the bot sees is that a particular test is a $\chi^2$ test, and that a certain $\chi^2$ value, $df$, and $p$-value were reported.